# Method of lines in a single PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

After solving this following PDE in NDSolve, now I have to use the method of lines to solve it and then compare the results. I was following the tutorial from Wolfram for Method of lines (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), perhaps, I'm in trouble whith this cillindrical coordinates. My difficult is to substitute the "r" with values of rMesh. Does anyone have a tip to fix it?

The PDE problem:

[image]

My adapted code:

```
u0 = 0; R = 0.425; R0 = 1/1000000; v = 0.09; rho = 1; w = 6*Pi; dPdL = 1; dPdZ = -`dPdL*Cos[w*t]; tF = 1;

n = 10; h = (R - R0)/n; rMesh = Table[r[i] -> (R0 + i*h), {i, 1, n}];

U[t_] = Table[u[i][t], {i, 0, n}];

gammai = ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}/h, U[t], {1, 2}, {u[n - 1][t]}]; (* dUdr *)
deltai = ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/h^2, U[t], {1, 2}, {u[n - 1][t]}]; (* d2Udr2*)

eqns = Thread[ D[U[t], t] == Join[{0}, v/r*(gammai + r*deltai) - 1/rho*dPdZ]];

initc = Thread[U[0] == Table[0, {n + 1}]];

lines = NDSolve[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, 1}, {r, R0, R}]
```

The screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
(* Method of lines parameters *)
n = 20; xmax = 0.425; xmin = 
 1/1000000; Subscript[h, n] = (xmax - xmin)/n; sf = 1; dcv = 0; tF = 1;
(* model parameters *)
v = 0.09; rho = 1; w = 6*Pi; dPdL = 1; dPdZ = -dPdL*Cos[w*t];
(* discretizations *)
U[t_] = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, 0, n}];
R = Subdivide[xmin, xmax, n];
fo = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1, R, U[t]];
lap = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2, R, U[t]];
(* set up DirichletCondition at wall *)
bc0 = Last[U[t]] == dcv;
bc0d = Map[D[#, t] + sf # &, bc0];
(* set up no flux condition at centerline *)
bc1 = First[fo] == 0;
bc1d = Map[D[#, t] &, bc1];
(* set up ODE system *)
eqns = Thread[D[U[t], t] == v lap + (1/R) . fo - 1/rho*dPdZ];
eqns[[-1]] = bc0d;
eqns[[1]] = bc1d;
ics = Thread[U[0] == Table[0, {n + 1}]];
diffsol = NDSolve[{eqns, ics}, U[t], {t, 0, tF}];
(* Create Interpolation Functions for Easier Plotting *)
ifn = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{t, xmin + i Subscript[h, n]}, 
      First[Subscript[u, i][t] /. diffsol]}, {i, 0, n}, {t, 0, tF, 
      tF/n}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Plot3D[ifn[t, x], {t, 0, tF}, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]